# Match on lines that have one string and NOT another

Tags: python-3.x

I am able to match strings in lines of a file like so:

```
re.search(r"\b10/100/1000\b", line) and re.search(r"notco*", line):
```

However, I need to be able to match lines that have one string, UNLESS they have another.

Example: Match pattern of '40G' unless the line also contains the pattern 'Po'

Comment: for instance like `re.search("40G",line) and not re.search("Po",line)` ? or do you mean "in a single regex"

Comment: YES!  Well, that was easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just negate the second search:

```
re.search("40G",line) and not re.search("Po",line)
```

if no need for regex, then ... no need for regex, use `in`:

```
"40G" in line and "Po" not in line
```